# Making a Map with a Legend as a .pdf Without a White Background

Tags: arcmap, cartography, arcgis-10.1, legend

I have a shapefile of United States counties.  I also have an Excel file of the share of the black population in each county.  I'd like to make a map of this using GIS.  (Before you say that there are ways to do this outside of GIS, yes I realize that, but I would like to do this in GIS, so please let us not go there.)

I am not at all sure how to go about this.

Starting backwards:
First, I have my shapefile loaded.  I know I can save the shapefile as say a .jpg or .pdf under File -> Export Map and then change the Save as Type of .jpg or .pdf.  However, when I do so, I get some white in the background from GIS.  Is there a way to do this without getting the whtie in the background?

Second, how would I include a legend in the map?

Third, is there a way I can indicate different shades of one color to mean different things?  Like a dark blue is more than 2/3 black, light blue is between 1/3 and 2/3 and white is less than 1/3?

Fourth, how do I merge the data on the black population in?  I suppose worst case, I can type it in manually by hand.  But preferably I wouldn't have to.  Is there a way to rearrange the Excel file so that I can merge it in?  Like can I merge it in using the fips codes if both files have that?

I use ArcMap in ArcGIS 10.1.

I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: This [ESRI article](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17336) says that there are problems with transparency in export from ArcGIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To start with I will drop this [website](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/home/) as a resource you should tie into.
your sequences are actually backward. your fourth has to be the first thing you attempt. (something I learned long ago is to plan what you want to end up with and then work back to where you are so you are sure you will end up with what you want [not something else]).

[image: image1]
 1. you need a key between the counties and the xls data.
 2. add your xls with the add button.
[image: image2]
 3. join the xls to the shapefile with the key. (I am using the fips code).
 [image: image3] 
[image: image4]
[image: image6]
 4. open the layer properties dialog and go the the symbology tab. 
         (you haven't been clear enough on the data format/type for the next step)
 5. choose "quantities"> Graduated colors and then the classify button.

[image: image7]
[image: image8]
[image: image8.1]
 6. Switch to layout view and insert a legend export to jpg and open with your favorite image editor software.
    There are 2 ways to switch to layout view (you may already be in layout view).
          1. from the view pulldown.
          2. from the icons in the lower left of the data window 
            (right of the table of contents)
[image: image9]
 6.5 Then use the insert pulldown and insert a legend onto the layout (within the page size you have set up).
[image: image10]
 7. click (in the layout) and select the "data frame". Then right click and modify the properties. make the border no color.
[image: image11]
[image: image 12]
 8. File pulldown> export map, and choose the format you want.
[image: image13]

Generally you should understand that ALL images are rectangular. There must be a color within that rectangle.  If you don't want the edges to show up you must first make the image compatible with transarency, and then assign the color you want to be transparent.  There is still a value there fo rthat color it is just that "some" software recognize the transparent tag and "turn" off that color.

Comment: In the end you can export your map to SVG and remove the white background in Inkscape.

Comment: You can't really remove. You just have to pick a color (1) for transparency.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Most power users would have felt that this is an easy enough procedure, but your answer makes it easy enough for even a Novice at GIS.

Comment: @BradNesom Thank you Brad so much for walking me through this!  I am far from a power user, so this was incredibly helpful.  I really don't know how I would have figured this out otherwise.

Comment: @BradNesom I think I figured out the fist five steps.  I do not know how to thank you enough for your detail!!  May I please ask you about the last 1.5 steps?  I am in the layout view.  What exactly are you saying to do with the legend?  Also, is there a way to get the transparent image without using an image editor software?  Ultimately I would like to make the map as a .pdf.  I worry that editing it (I use paint) will make it look a little distorted in converting from GIS -> jpeg -> edited Paint -> .pdf rather than GIS -> .pdf.

Comment: @BradNesom Thank you for these edits!  They are incredibly helpful! :)  I don't want to have color because I ultimately want to import the file into a document, and I want the map to blend in with the background of the document, rather than have a distinct background remaining from GIS.  As it stands, I think the map would get inserted with a frame around it from GIS.  I'm not sure how to upload an example of how I'd like this to look.  However, I could provide an example link of such a document with such a map and refer you to a page in that link if that would clarify.

Comment: Sure, If I understand correctly you will need to do one of two things.  set the transparency or set the background to the desired color of your document background.

Comment: @BradNesom I think so, although I don't know what transparency means.  The document background is white.  I just want the map to appear without a box around it and with a white background

Comment: @BradNesom Thank you for adding these last steps!!  They are so clear!! Thank you, thank you!  May I ask in the color selection, is it possible to set a color manually?  In particular, I would like the spectrum to be such that the smallest value is white and the other value(s) are the blue color wheel?  This is in contrast to say using the blue color wheel for all values.

Comment: If you are asking about step 5. then just simpply click on the single color you want ans set to white.. then select all the other colors and then select the color ramp you want. I believe you can also create your own color ramps "in the style manager"

Comment: Yes, I did mean Step 5, thank you for your explanation.   I found that after choosing a set of colors through the color ramp, if you double click on 1 color in the symbol directly, about 20 options appear from which you can replace that particular 1.  Is that what you had in mind?  Where is the style manager?

Comment: yes for the white you want. Then with several of the other values selected just select the arrow next to the color ramp and choose the color ramp you want. it will apply that ramp to the selection (or if you don't have anything selected to everything). I added a screenshot of the style manager pulldown. That is where you would create your own ramps.

Comment: Is it possible to make the map such that the county boundaries are lighter (or maybe even removed though probably lighter is ideal)?

Comment: there are several ways. It depends on the data (feature type) and the effect you want. BTW all this can be learned on arcgis.com and mappingcenter.esri.com

Comment: How do I know what the feature type of the data are?

Comment: polygon, point, line

Comment: Oh, I believe that I am working with a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

For adding legend go to the menu Insert/Legend ([see this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000007000000) and [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000023000000)).

For symbology colors go to layer Properties/Symbology, read [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_graduated_colors/00s500000029000000/).

Excel file you can add as a table and then join with the shapefile, if you have fields with the same values in both. About adding Excel file check [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_how_to_use_Microsoft_Excel_files_in_ArcGIS/005s0000001w000000/) and next two pages. About joining tables [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) chapter.

Comment: How does the legend factor into this?

Comment: In the upper menu File, Edit, View ... click at [Insert](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/00s9/GUID-79DB7D6F-6638-4725-898E-7C0D14699EEE-web.png) and chose Legend. This [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000023000000) shows how to configure the legend and [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sm00000007000000) how to export to pdf.

Comment: Also, take a look at this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13699/transparency-for-pdfs-in-arc