# Exporting inset map with same quality in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export

I am having trouble exporting my map that has the same quality in the inset.  The lines come out blurry.

[image: Main vs. Inset]

You can see a big difference between the quality.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are they in the same Layout view ? Do you have two data frames ?

Comment: 2 separate data frames, same layout view.

Comment: What kind of file did you export to ? You may need to go to PDF options and play it around until you figure it out. Do you know how to go to PDF Options ?

Comment: It looks like you're rasterizing your layers in the inset, this could mean that one of the higher (later drawing) layers has transparency set; put transparent layers below vector layers or turn transparency off. How does it look on screen? I'm assuming it looks great in ArcMap but the export is pixelated. If you can't adjust transparency up the resolution of the output image - PDF can go to 720.

Comment: Related to (maybe possible duplicate of) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13699/transparency-for-pdfs-in-arc

Comment: I export to pdf.  I have played with every setting imaginable.  I also cannot bump the DPI up as it distorts my linetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running this in the python window (for both frames), just to make sure all of your transparencies are off:

`import arcpy`

def DetectRasterization():
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  df_list = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
  foundRasterization = False
  noneFoundMsg = "No rasterizing layers were detected."
  for df in df_list:
    lyr_list = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, data_frame=df)
    for lyr in lyr_list:
      if lyr.isRasterizingLayer or lyr.supports("BRIGHTNESS"):
        foundRasterization = True
        if lyr.isGroupLayer and lyr.transparency > 0:
          print "In data frame '" + df.name + "', the group layer '" + \
                   lyr.longName + "' is a rasterizing layer:\r",
          print "\tVisibility is " + str(lyr.visible) + ".\n" + \
                "\tTransparency is " + str(lyr.transparency) + " percent.\n"
        elif not lyr.isGroupLayer:
          print "In data frame '" + df.name + "', the layer '" + \
                   lyr.longName + "' is a rasterizing layer:\r",
          if lyr.transparency > 0:
            print "\tVisibility is " + str(lyr.visible) + ".\n" + \
                  "\tTransparency is " + str(lyr.transparency) + " percent.\n"
          else:
            print "\tVisibility is " + str(lyr.visible) + ".\n" + \
                  "\tTransparency is 0 percent, but the layer may be a\n" + \
                  "\traster layer or contain rasterizing symbology such\n" + \
                  "\tas bitmap picture symbols.\n"
      del lyr
    del lyr_list
    del df
  if not foundRasterization:
    print noneFoundMsg
  del df_list
  del mxd

DetectRasterization()

It is easy to miss a layer or two when you have a lot going on.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent layers cause any vector layers underneath it to be rasterized in the output pdf.  I can see that you have a transparent layer in both dataframes.  The blue polygon at the top left of the screenshot has a pixelated border (In the main dataframe).  When you zoom in (inset), the pixels of all the rasterized layers become more visible.

As @Michael Miles-Stimson said, try moving your transparent layer as far down the stack as you can.  (Do those lines really need to be covered by the transparent layer?  Bring them up to the top and they will export as vectors).

Here is another answer explaining transparency in ArcMap:  [Transparency for PDFs in Arc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13699/transparency-for-pdfs-in-arc)  (Thanks @faith_dur).

Comment: I adjusted all of my layers and all layers in the inset are still coming out blurry.  It is as if the Inset data frame is being processed completely separately at a lower resolution and being pasted on top.

Comment: As an experiment, will you please try this:  1. Locate all layers that have transparency enabled.  2. Turn off those layers.  3. Export the map.  Is the inset still blurry?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in ArcMap 10.6. Export to PDF became rasterised- vectors were lost.
I find out that in some cases if you have group layers PDF becomes rasterised.
I have simply reordered my layers all under one "root" layer and export was vectorised PDF.