# Exported PDF from ArcMap pixelated

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, pdf, layouts

I am currently creating two similar maps with the same basic layers, including same basemap.  I am exporting the mxd as a pdf with the exact same parameters, yet one comes out pixelated, and one is smooth (see attachments).  I have tried different options for export from Compression to Picture Symbol (i.e. switch default from "rasterize layers with bitmap markers/fills" to "vectorize..." yet no improvement on pixelated figure.  Data is the same for figure samples.

Pixelated map is 3Mb and the smooth map is 1Mb.

Has anybody experienced a similar issue?

ArcMap 10.6

[image: smooth figure]
Smooth figure
[image: pixelated figure]
Pixelated figure

Comment: So a lazy attempt to find answer on my end.  I found the solution from a 4 year old post with similar but more specific topic.  I will reference the answer here and leave it up to the moderators to determine whether I should just delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Highest ranked comment by @Michael Stimson on below post/question nailed it.  I had a transparent layer close to top of Table of Contents.  Apparently that vectorizes other layers upon output.  So I removed the transparency (you can also just move it lower apparently).

[Exporting inset map with same quality in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240116/exporting-inset-map-with-same-quality-in-arcgis-desktop/240143#240143)